# ActionScript - Private Parameters?

Tags: actionscript-3, parameters, private, forwarding

is it possible to mark parameters as private, only accessible/useful for the class that owns the function?

example:

```
//PRIVATE CLASS (.SWC)
public function set AutoBounce(value:Boolean):void
     {
     if (value)
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bounce);
        else
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bounce);
     }

public function bounce():void //incorrect signature
     {
     //bounce ball
     }
```

the above bounce() method signature is incorrect.  to facilitate the event listeners, it needs to be `public function bounce(evt:MouseEvent):void`.  however, i don't want the user of the class to have to supply this parameter when calling the bounce() function.  therefore, if i could mark the evt:MouseEvent parameter as private or hidden from the calling class, it would solve the problem.

currently, i'm simply redirecting the event listener to a forwarding function:

```
//PRIVATE CLASS (.SWC)
public function set AutoBounce(value:Boolean):void
     {
     if (value)
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, forwardBounce);
        else
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, forwardBounce);
     }

private function forwardBounce(evt:MouseEvent):void
     {
     bounce();
     }

public function bounce():void
     {
     //bounce ball
     }
```

rather than redirecting, is there any better way to dealing with this issue?  maybe "better way" is a poor choice of words.  is there a way to refactor this code without using a forwarding function or having to force the user to include the event parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just say this if you wanted to be able to call `bounce` without the required MouseEvent:

```
public function bounce(evt:MouseEvent=null):void
{
    //...
}
```

FYI, bounce doesn't need to be public... it too can be a private function. Unfortunately, AS3 doesn't support overloading.

Comment: that would work for refactoring.  however, this approach allows the user to supply that public function with a MouseEvent they would see with code hinting (which wouldn't do anything and seem confusing).

Comment: bounce() is public.  the user can call it.  they can also, optionally, toggle an autoBounce property that would or wouldn't automatically call bounce() for them.

Comment: True. I'd have to say your current method would be best.